# Entity Framework stored procedure error with DateTime

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Hi
I am getting an error 
 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'
When calling a stored procedure using EF4.

I am passing from my c# 2 DateTimes like this

@FromDate='2010-11-10 12:30:14.2558729'
@ToDate= '2010-11-10 12:30:15.1169590'

How can I prevent this error?

if I do the following in my UI it works

```
FromDate = new DateTime   (SelectedFromDate.Year,SelectedFromDate.Month,SelectedFromDate.Day),
ToDate = new DateTime(SelectedToDate.Year, SelectedToDate.Month, SelectedToDate.Day),
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the number of digits on the fractional seconds to three.  Try it out...

What you are trying to do:

```
select convert(datetime,'2010-11-10 12:30:14.2558729')
--                                           ^^^^^^^
```

OUTPUT:

```
-----------------------
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
```

Using only 3 decimal digits:

```
select convert(datetime,'2010-11-10 12:30:14.255')
--                                           ^^^
```

OUTPUT:

```
-----------------------
2010-11-10 12:30:14.257

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: that works in sql however how Am I going to do in the SP if I pass 2 params @FromDate and @ToDate.If fails before giving the chance to convert it

Comment: make the string shorter in C# before calling the stored procedure OR have the stored procedure parameter data type be varchar(27) and then store the first 23 characters of the input parameter into a local variable of `datetime` type, like: `DECLARE @FromDate_D datetime; set @FromDate_D=LEFT(@FromDate,23)`, where @FromDate is your varchar(27) input parameter.